# Django App - Brand New Car Calculator - SQL or OOP structure?

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, oop

I'm writing web app in Django 2 - brand new car calculator. I don't know which data structure to choose - relational or object oriented database.

It is well known solution where you choose first model, then type (sedan, combi, etc.), color.

The problem occurs when you choose engine, transmission (automatic, manual) equipment, extra packages. As you know there is so many options and not all are possible to choose.

For example, you can't choose 1.0 petrol engine with automatic transmission and four-wheel drive.

My first choice was object-oriented programming with inheritance but I can't find how to limit options in subclasses.

Any of you did run a similar project?

best regards

Comment: This is more of a design specific question than a technical programming one and StackOverflow is mainly used for the latter. At a glance, you could go SQL and create junction tables (many to many) for options `CAR <- CAR/OPTION -> OPTION`. When a user clicks on their make, model, type then all the available options will populate. The junction table can hold the price as leather for a smaller car might be cheaper than for an SUV.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen. I appreciate your honest answer and solution I have to consider. Take care!